# How do I get QWebView to release threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am creating a lot of QWebViews which each create QThreads. The problem is that I am running out of stack space to create more threads. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to clean up existing threads. To be clear, I am not the one creating these threads: Qt creates the threads when I show a QWebView.

Most of the threads (about 400/500) have the exact same stack:

```
0  ntdll!RtlEnableEarlyCriticalSectionEventCreation C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll  0   0x770b013d  
1   KERNEL32!GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameA       C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll    0   0x766d1a2c  
2   USER32!MessageBoxA                              C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll  0   0x74cd086a  
3   QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents            qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    831 0x69de3948  
4   QEventLoop::processEvents                       qeventloop.cpp  149 0x69dbf0c5  
5   QEventLoop::exec                                qeventloop.cpp  204 0x69dbf223  
6   QThread::exec                                   qthread.cpp 501 0x69cd412b  
7   QThread::run                                    qthread.cpp 568 0x69cd4283  
8   QThreadPrivate::start                           qthread_win.cpp 346 0x69cd54d1  
9   msvcrt!_itow_s                                  C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll  0   0x75401287  
10  msvcrt!_endthreadex                             C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll  0   0x75401328  
11  KERNEL32!BaseCleanupAppcompatCacheSupport       C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll    0   0x766d339a  
12  ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey                         C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll   0   0x770c9ef2  
13  ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey                         C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll   0   0x770c9ec5  
14  ??      0
```

Is there any way to clean them up?

Comment: Assuming they're internal to QWebView, the only way to get rid of them would be to delete the QWebView instance. (even if you could close the threads behind the web view's back, it would break the functionality of the webview). How many views do you create at once here?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld a few hundred apparently...thats the problem: I want to be able to have even more than that. Is there a way to tell QWebView to close its threads?

Comment: I would recommend to reconsider your design and avoid opening so many web views. Even if I open several hundreds of tabs in my browser, I expect it will not work consistently.

Comment: Given that a WebView has a javascript engine, your expectation of being able to create a few hundred of them is a few years ahead of its time :) I'm sure in 2020 you will be able to get a "cheap" desktop system with 64G of RAM at a big box retailer and pull this stunt off :)

Comment: @KubaOber nope, javascript is disabled. therefore, there is no need for a javascript thread. I think that the thread was allocated for asynchronous network requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I realized that the thread was allocated for the NetworkManager, I created a global NetworkManager instance and set it to the NetworkAccessManager of every QWebView. This allowed it to reuse the same group of threads for all of the pages and thus doesnt leave many threads laying around.