# Disable multithreading in QWebView

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qwebview

I use QWebView to display local web pages in my application (they are used as help). I have found that QWebView creates a separate thread by default to display a webpage. Is there a way to disable creating separate thread?

Comment: Are you sure it's the QWebView? You may have a look here: [SO - How do I get QWebView to release threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618439/how-do-i-get-qwebview-to-release-threads)

Comment: "Is there a way to disable creating separate thread?" Why do you care?